# What is the partial derivative of the following function?

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

Can you help me to compute the partial derivative $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ of the following function ?

$g(x)=\frac{1}{2}(x-y)^TM(x-y)+h^2(\frac{1}{2}x^TLx-x^TJd+x^Tf_e)$

where :
$x,y,f_e\in\mathbb{R}^n$
$d\in\mathbb{R}^s$
$M,L\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ **and symmetrics** ($M=M^T$ and $L=L^T$)
$J\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times s}$
$h\in\mathbb{R}$

I've computed :
$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=(M+h^2L)x-h^2Jd+\frac{1}{2}My+h^2f_e$

Am I right ?

Comment: What is $T$? the transpose?

Comment: @LuisValerin, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basics derivatives are
$$\nabla Ax=A\qquad\nabla x^TA=A^T\qquad\nabla x^TAx=x^T(A+A^T)$$
Then
$$\nabla g(x)=\frac12(x-y)^T(M+M^T)+h^2\Big(\frac12x^T(L+L^T)-(Jd)^T+f_e^T\Big)\\=(x-y)^TM+h^2(x^TL-d^TJ^T+f_e^T)$$

Comment: Are you sure that the derivative of $(x-y)^TA(x-y)$ is $(x-y)^T(A+A^T)$ ? There is no development to do before the derivation ?

Comment: @Michael Yes. You can verify it through either expanding it or applying chain rule.

Comment: Yeah ok, you're right. So, if I want to isolate $x$ and with a column notation, the final result is : $(M+h^2L)x-h^2Jd+h^2f_e-My$ ?

Comment: @Michael Exactly.